# Dart project structure for apps (not libs)

Tags: dart, dart-pub, project-structure

I am trying to understand Dart's [recommended project structure](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout) and not seeing the "forest through the trees".

So, if my project is *intended* to be a reusable library, say, a logging framework of some sort, then if I understand the above link correctly, I want all of my development to be under a `lib` and `lib/src` directory.

But what if I am building a web app? Where do my Dart source files go? Under `packages`? Specifically:

1. Where do I place Dart source files for a web app (not a lib)?
2. Are my web app's "packages" just directories that are logically organized similar to Java packages?
3. Does Dart recommend a 1-class-per-file convention for its source code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1)

- your_app_package/web
- your_app_package/web/src/xxx

static content like jpg, css go to
* your_app_package/asset

2) the packages directory is maintained automatically. You configure in the file `pubspec.yaml` which 3rd party libraries you want to use and then call `pub get` or `pub upgrade` and the `packages` directory is updated automatically (the Darteditor does this automatically when you update `pubspec.yaml`).

3) not that I know of.

I had some problems putting additional classed in the code file of a Polymer element though. But I guess this is just a temporary limitation of Polymer.

Comment: Thanks @zoechi (+1)! To clarify, you're saying that if my web app is called `fizzbuzz`, then I should put all the Dart code for it under `fizzbuz/web` **or** `fizzbuzz/web/src`? Thanks again!

Comment: @TicketMonster exactly, including any 'dynamic' HTML files (the ones you Dart code operates on).

You can place other files like static HTML, CSS, IMG here too but as discussed they will better fit to asset in the future.